# c#: How to delete a newly inserted record which is not committed by a transaction

Tags: c#, sqltransaction

I want to delete a record which is inserted in the previous step inside one transaction.

The transaction is created without any isolation level defined.

Currently, no record is deleting by delete statement.

Comment: Rollback the transaction?

Comment: Don't commit the transaction *or* explicitly roll it back. If you want more help you will have to provide more context, preferably an [mcve].

Comment: "Transaction is created without any isolation level defined" that is not possible actually, you just have some default isolation level.

Comment: You could wrap this particular insert in a nested transaction and then cancel it, to understand if you are able to do that indicate what RDBMS you are using.

Comment: What is the problem you have? You can insert and delete the row you just added in the transaction. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 0):

> begin trans
>
> ################################
>
> insert your sql statement here
>
> ################################
>
> rollback -- if you want to cancel your transactions
>      commit -- if
>   you feel good about your transactions